# I bought a new ECU and installed it. GMC Acadia 07. After key relearn it killed the power and key is stuck in ignition. What's going on?

Tags: key, program

I have a 2007 GMC Acadia. I bought a new ECU and installed it. It has a brand new battery in it and it's been pre programmed to the vin number when I ordered it. When I went to do the key program procedure it was doing what it's supposed to do, but when I went to crank it all the power shut off and my key got locked into the ignition on the on position and would not go back to the off position. I manually released the key by holding the switch behind the steering wheel and when I go to try it again... no power and it gets stuck in the on position again. I've called locksmiths and they don't know what's going on please help.

Comment: Your descriptions may be all about main power; battery, battery cables and their connections to main fuse panel, starter, chassis and engine block grounds. If a new battery, is it fully charged? Are both battery connections clean, secured, and free of powdery residue from dried battery acid? Are both main grounds clean, secured and free of corrosion?